# Coordinate for dragging the captcha slider

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

Please help me, I work in BAS, I need to calculate the coordinate in order to drag the slider.

I have browser resolution: 1280x720
I have the size of the area itself where the captcha is located - x=470; y=540 (this is the upper left corner). Photo pictures: https://vk.cc/co3eY5

The answer comes to me that inside this square the coordinates are: {"status":1,"request":"coordinates:x=487,y=202,w=98"}

I've been sitting for two hours, I can't guess, math is not my thing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.